# Problema depurando un thread cuando existen varios activos Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Tengo un programa que llegado un punto lanza un task donde se ejecutan una serie de acciones, mientras esas acciones estoy en un bucle comprobando hasta que termina ese task o se llega a una determinada fecha.
Lo que quiero es depurar unicamente lo que sucede en ese task, en concreto en el codigo **enviosCompletados()**
Actualmente me salta aleatoriamente entre el codigo del bucle y el propio task.
Os adjunto el codigo a ver si alguien puede ayudarme:

```
       Thread thread = null;

        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
            enviosCompletados();
        });

        DateTime fin = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second).AddMinutes(minutosProceso);
        while (!t.IsCompleted && (DateTime.Now < fin))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(300);
        }
```

Gracias.

Comment: si pones un break point dentro de la funcion que dispara el otro thread, no debugueas ahi?

Comment: Por cierto, en lugar de ese feo bucle while, por que no usar `await` con un timeout?

Comment: @pikoh hola, pues porque no sabia que existia eso hasta que acabo de leerte jejeje

Comment: @gbianchi  si,  pero aleatoriamente tambien me va al bucle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes decirle al debugger que solo haga break en un thread en específico en este caso el creado por el ´StartNew()´

1. Abre la ventana de Breakpoints (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> )
2. Clic derecho en un breakpoint que esté dentro de `enviosCompletados`
3. Settings...
4. Activa Conditions
5. Escoge Filter
6. En la expresión puedes colocar `ThreadId = xxx`  donde xxx es el numero del thread.

Además para que funcione correctamente debes desactivar los demás breakpoints